# while adding poi -ooxml dependency in sts4 I am getting an error - cannot transfer

Tags: java, apache-poi, pom.xml

I am getting an error while adding poi - ooxlm dependency in my Rest assured project . I need to add Excel file interaction to handle data .
The error I am getting is "Could not transfer artifact org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:jar:5.2.2 from/to snapshots (https://artifacts.apple.com/libs-snapshot): artifacts.apple.com org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could
not transfer artifact org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:jar:5.2.2 from/to snapshots (https://artifacts.apple.com/libs-snapshot): artifacts.apple.com at "

my pom.xml is
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show much of the relevant parts of your `pom.xml`; also including the relevant snippets as text is easier than a screenshot.

But [org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-lite/5.2.2) is available on [maven central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/), so that's where your project should look.

`https://artifacts.apple.com/libs-snapshot` does not resolve for me, this might be a company internal maven repository that you're using?

There are a few things you can check:

- Open the file `.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml-lite\5.2.2\poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.2.jar.lastUpdated` and check the error message for each repository. Check why it can't reach maven central; is it missing from the list or giving an error? This might be a company firewall/policy issue perhaps? Or is it giving an error on HTTPS/TLS protocol level?
- Check with `mvn help:effective-pom` what your current listed (plugin) repositories are
- Check if you can add maven central to your repositories list if it's missing somehow (should be included by default). Check if it's `HTTP` or `HTTPS`, only secure is supported now.
- Check in your main maven repository which versions of this jar are available / mirrored, and depend on that version instead (if you can't get maven central to work).
- Run your maven command with `-X` for debug mode to investigate further